# MySQL ORDER BY multiple column ASC and DESC not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have 1 mySQL table. Table entries are:

[image]

I want to show a list under 2 conditions. First the highest **right_answers** and also depending on lowest **time_spent**

I used this sql code to retrieve the list

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `contest_id` = '2' ORDER BY right_answers desc,time_spent")
```

I am getting this output:

[image]

My expected output shoulb be:

[image]

I tried many times with different queries but the result is still wrong. Could you give me some solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide full table create statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your `time_spent` column has a `VARCHAR(x)` datatype, not a numeric datatype. So, MySQL is ordering the values in alphabetical order like this.

```
 1
 10
 259
 46
 5
 6
 7894
 9
```

Your best repair of this problem is to change the datatype of that column to `INT`. (Also repair the right_answers column.)

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN time_spent time_spent INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN right_answers right_answers INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

Then your `ORDER BY` operation will work numerically and give you expected results.

Your second best repair is to coerce the data to numeric in your `ORDER BY` clause, like this:

```
 ORDER BY 0+right_answers DESC, 0+time_spent ASC
```

Comment: Yesssss!!! I got the problem now. Code is alright, My time_spent column was a TEXT datatype. Now it's okey and working fine....

Answer (score 0):

You try this way,I am trying its working

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `contest_id` = '2' ORDER BY table_name.right_answers desc,time_spent ASC");

Comment: It's output is same as mine

Comment: you query produce same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_name` WHERE `contest_id` = '2' 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING( time_spent
FROM 1 
FOR 1 ) ASC , right_answers DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `contest_id` = '2' and id in (SELECT ID FROM `table_name` ORDER BY right_answers DESC) ORDER BY time_spent ASC")

interchange column names and try again.